# Как скачать json файл с помощью библиотеки guzzle на php?

Tags: php, guzzle

По данному адресу https://panel.777spy.com/get_stats открывается в браузере json файл[image: как видно его в браузере]

Требуется авторизация на сайте, чтобы увидеть, поэтому скрин приложил. Для авторизации и скачки использую guzzle на php. И всё проходит, и авторизация, и скачка файла. НО скачивается он пустой только с одним словом - 'anon'. Почему он нормально не скачивается?

```
    <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();

$resource = fopen('get_stats.json', 'w');

// создаем нового клиента
$client = new Client([
  'base_uri' => 'https://panel.777spy.com', 
  'verify'  => false,                        
      'allow_redirects' => false,            
      'headers' => [                         
          'User-Agent'   => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux 3.4; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0',
          'Accept'       => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // кодирование данных формы, в такой кодировке браузер отсылает данные на сервер
      ]
]);

/**
* В метод request передается три параметра:
*
*
* 1. Методы GET, POST
* 2. URL на который отправляются данные формы
* 3. forms_params - значения логина и пароля
*/
$login = $client -> request('GET','/get_stats',[
  'form_params' => [
    'login'    => '',
    'password' => ''
  ],
  'headers' => [
        'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
  'sink' => $resource
]);

echo 'downloaded';
```

Comment: а вы уверены, что логин и пароль должны передаваться в таком виде как вы их передаёте?

Comment: в самом скрипте я не передаю их пустыми, здесь просто убрал. Или что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: то что они идут в form_params и называются login, password.

Comment: через auth передавать?

Comment: Я не знаю как нужно передавать. Может там вообще сначала токен нужно получить, а потом с ним по этому адресу обращаться. Смотрите на заголовки в браузере у этого запроса и имитируйте в php